# add class to anchor in jQuery

Tags: javascript

is it possible to add a class to the anchor in the code below? because i have a conflict with other anchors...

```
function SelectText(element) {
  var doc = document;
  var text = doc.getElementById(element);    
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(text);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(text);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}


$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    SelectText( $(this).attr("rel") );
  });
})
```

**EDIT:**
I want to catch all code in a code block and use the rel attribute for it.
I use this php line for it:

```
$output ='<br /><br /><a rel="highlight'.$element_id.'" class="selectable">[Select All]</a>'; // assign unique ID to rel attribute
```

The div in which the code is has the same unique ID, so i use the rel to catch the code.
But somehow it gives me a problem with the other anchors, they do not work correctly anymore. So i thought: if i add a class to the anchor, it might be listening only to the a with that specific class name

Comment: In which part of the code? In the `SelectText` function? or elsewhere?

Comment: What's the problem?  What "conflict" are you having?  Where do you want to add a class?  When do you want to add a class?  How do you want to add a class?  What is the *exact* problem are you having?  I do not understand this question at all.

Comment: Add when? On click? On `ready`? When the sun goes down?

Comment: Why not? Simply add a `class` or `id` attribute to the `A` element and update the jQuery selector

Comment: Following up on your clarification, modify your selector from `$('a')` to `$('a.selectable')`, perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).addClass()`. That is the element being clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selectable');
    }
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Or if you are talking about using the `click` handler only for `a` tags with the class `selectable` you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.selectable').click(function() {
        SelectText( $(this).attr("rel") );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an ID to the anchor you want to add a class to, then with jquery, you can use `.addClass()` - http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

I.E.

```
$( "#yourAnchorID" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );
```

Comment: This will add it to all anchor tags though. That's probably not what the OP wants.